# Swiper.JS Next Button moving 1.5 slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using Swiper.JS to create a two row card slider.

**Problem:** 
When pressing the next button, instead of transitioning to the next slide, the slider moves about 1.5 slides in total, which leaves the next slide cut in half and nearly skipped entirely. This happens each time the next button is clicked.

**What I want:** 
For the slider to display the next slide entirely, and it would be nice if it were centered.

**What I have tried:** 
I have tried using the centeredSlides attribute, but it breaks the swiper. I have also tried defining slidesPerGroup as 1, but this does nothing. I've also inspected the rendered page to see if a width was being generated by the slider, but I cannot see anything.

**Question:** 
Has anyone encountered this problem before? And does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is the JS for the slider that I am currently using:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    grid: {
      rows: 1,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      550: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        grid: {
          rows: 2
        }
      },
      1000: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        grid: {
          rows: 2
        }
      },
      1360: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        grid: {
          rows: 2
        }
      }
    },
    spaceBetween: 30,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
  });
```

The HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="conference-speakers-container">



<!-- Conference Speakers -->
    {{-- Title --}}
    <div class="conference-speakers-title-container">
        <span class="title-word-blue">CONFERENCE</span><span class="title-word-black">SPEAKERS</span>
    </div>

<!-- Conference Speakers Body -->
    {{-- Slider Buttons --}}
    <!--button type="button" class="conference-speaker-slider-left-arrow" onClick="conference_speaker_slide_right()" id="conference_speaker_slider_left_arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="conference-speaker-slider-right-arrow" onClick="conference_speaker_slide_left()" id="conference_speaker_slider_right_arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button-->

    {{-- Conference Speaker Cards --}}
    <div class="conference-speakers" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/images/Unscripted-Background-Light.png'?>);">

        <!--Swiper: Uses www.swiperjs.com to add touch screen functionality and easy swiping-->
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="conference-speakers-cards-container container swiper-wrapper" data-chunksize="6">
                <?php 

                if ( !function_exists('wpeventin')) {
                    echo 'Please Install and Activate the WP Event Solution plugin in order to use the Speakers Section';
                } else {
                    wp_reset_query();
                    $speaker_array = [];
                    $args = [
                        'post_type' => 'etn-speaker',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1 
                    ];

                    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        while($the_query->have_posts()) {
                            $the_query->the_post();
                            $speaker_avatar = apply_filters("etn/speakers/avatar", \Wpeventin::assets_url() . "images/avatar.jpg");
                            $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                            $speaker_data = [
                                'speaker_name' => apply_filters('etn_speaker_title', get_the_title()),
                                'speaker_designation' => $post_meta["etn_speaker_designation"][0],
                                'speaker_thumbnail' => has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : $speaker_avatar,
                                'speaker_permalink' => get_the_permalink()
                            ];
                            
                            array_push($speaker_array, $speaker_data);
                        }
                    }

                    //<!-- SPEAKER CARD TEMPLATE -->

                    foreach($speaker_array as $speaker) { ;?>

                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <a href="<?php echo $speaker['speaker_permalink']; ?>">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $speaker['speaker_thumbnail'] ); ?>" alt="Picture of <?php echo $speaker['speaker_name']; ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title"><?php echo $speaker['speaker_name']; ?></div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation"><?php echo $speaker['speaker_designation']; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                <?php
                } 
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS (I use SCSS, but this is the compiled):

```
.conference-speakers-container {
     height: calc(100vh + 220px);
     width: 100vw;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .conference-speakers-title-container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: white;
     height: 125px;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .conference-speakers-title-container .title-word-blue {
     font-size: 2rem;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .conference-speakers-title-container .title-word-black {
     color: black;
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .conference-speakers {
     height: 100%;
     background-color: white;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: auto;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container {
     padding-top: 50px;
     padding-bottom: 125px;
     margin: auto;
     height: 100%;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide {
     max-width: 344px;
     height: calc((100% - 300px) / 2) !important;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper {
     box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 10px 15px -3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 6px -2px;
     max-width: 344px;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper:hover {
     transform: scale(1.02);
     transition: 0.25s;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper:hover .speaker-card-info-wrapper .speaker-card-title {
     color: #0073ae;
     text-decoration: underline;
     transition: 0.25s;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper .speaker-card-avatar-wrapper {
     height: 344px;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper .speaker-card-avatar-wrapper img {
     height: 344px;
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     object-position: center;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper .speaker-card-info-wrapper {
     background-color: white;
     color: #2c344a;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper .speaker-card-info-wrapper .speaker-card-title {
     font-size: 21px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: -5px;
}
 .conference-speakers-container .mySwiper .conference-speakers-cards-container .swiper-slide a .conference-speaker-card-wrapper .speaker-card-info-wrapper .speaker-card-designation {
     font-size: 15px;
}
```

HTML Compiled:

```
<div class="conference-speakers-container">



<!-- Conference Speakers -->
    
    <div class="conference-speakers-title-container">
        <span class="title-word-blue">CONFERENCE</span><span class="title-word-black">SPEAKERS</span>
    </div>

    
    <div class="conference-speakers" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/themes/unscripted/resources/images/Unscripted-Background-Light.png);">

        <!--Swiper: Uses www.swiperjs.com to add touch screen functionality and easy swiping-->
        <div class="swiper mySwiper swiper-grid swiper-grid-column swiper-initialized swiper-horizontal swiper-pointer-events">
            <div class="conference-speakers-cards-container container swiper-wrapper" data-chunksize="6" id="swiper-wrapper-d484eeee6c260e0a" aria-live="polite" style="width: 3366px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" role="group" aria-label="1 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/bro-broseph-brodude/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Bro Broseph Brodude">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Bro Broseph Brodude</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Day Drinker</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" role="group" aria-label="2 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/eleven/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Eleven">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Eleven</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Telepath</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="3 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/madison-nosidam/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Madison Nosidam">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Madison Nosidam</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Actor</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="4 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/sherry-port/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Sherry Port">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Sherry Port</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Brewer</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="5 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/bill-shakespear/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Bill Shakespear">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Bill Shakespear</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Slam Poet</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="6 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/bunny-man/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Bunny Man">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Bunny Man</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Professional Cuddler</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="7 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/second-wind/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Second Wind">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Second Wind</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Partier</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="8 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/dime-dozen/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Dime Dozen">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Dime Dozen</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Sculpter</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="9 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/allison-macgummary/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Allison MacGummary">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Allison MacGummary</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Flower Girl</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="10 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/dorothy-cansas/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Dorothy Cansas">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Dorothy Cansas</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Dreamer</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="11 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/ronda-sylvester/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/plugins/wp-event-solution/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Picture of Ronda Sylvester">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Ronda Sylvester</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Photographer</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        
                        <div class="swiper-slide" role="group" aria-label="12 / 12" style="width: 531px; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/etn-speaker/dee-regs/">
                                <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                                    <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/unscripted/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/jac-john-atkins-marketing-agency-client-photos-innu-development-10.jpg" alt="Picture of Dee Regs">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                        <div class="speaker-card-title">Dee Regs</div>
                                        <div class="speaker-card-designation">Artist</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    
                                                </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-controls="swiper-wrapper-d484eeee6c260e0a" aria-disabled="true"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-controls="swiper-wrapper-d484eeee6c260e0a" aria-disabled="false"></div>
        <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```